# gitignore in subdirectory is not allowing a whitelisted entry

Tags: git, gitignore

git is located in a subdirectory("web" folder) along with .gitignore.  The following gitignore code is giving me some issues.

```
**/app/themes/  #Should ignore all folders in the themes subdirectory
!*/app/themes/folder1  #allow one single folder and it's content to be versioned
```

I've tried a few combinations like /app/themes, and */app/themes -- any help would be wonderful! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do

```
app/themes/**
!app/themes/folder1
```

This will match all files in path url/app/themes. What you have in your first line is: *match all folders named* themes *which are a subfolder of* app *regardless of where* app *is*.
You don't wont to just have

```
app/themes
```

because that would ignore the entire folder, and not allow for the negation in the line after.

Comment: Wow, ok thanks! This worked -- but I only used 1 * not 2.  Clearly I need to call it a night.  I appreciate it!

Comment: The difference is that * will match all files and folders in the *themes* directory, ** will also match what is in the subfolders - but since gitignore works recursively anyway, it doesn't make a difference there. Glad I could help!

Comment: Does that mean the recursiveness in the matching was causing the exception not to work with the **?

Comment: I am not entirely sure why that would happen...it might be that the exception was telling git to track *folder1* (and not its contents)? You could try if `app/themes/** \n
!app/themes/folder1/* ` works